# Selecting multiple rows, where a difference in value is greater than x%

Tags: mysql, sql, select, window-functions, recursive-query

I'm facing the following problem...
Given this data:
table : votes

```
=========
  value
=========
   10
   25
   38
   90
   92
   93
   98
   100
   120
```

I would like to return the value only, if the difference between next and previously accepted value is bigger than 10% of the first one:

```
if abs(int(a)-int(b))*100/int(a) < 10:
  return True
```

So the end list should be (I have added % difference in square brackets):

```
==========
  result
==========
   10 ()
   25 (150%)
   38 (52%)
   90 (136%)
   100 (11%)
   120 (20%)
```

The query should also sort those values first.

I'm able to do it with code (as shown above), but haven't got any chance in coming even close to a direct query.

MySQL v.8.0.19

Comment: Easy in MySQL 8.x. Are you using MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: When providing an example, it's sometimes more helpful to include rows that fail the criteria.

Comment: 8.x, I have added in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0, you can do this with `lag()`. Assuming that you want to sort rows by `value`, that would be:

```
select value
from (
    select
        value,
        lag(value, 1, 0) over(order by value) lag_value
    from mytable t
) t
where value > lag_value * 1.10
```

If you want to use an different ordering column, then you can change the `order by` clause to use the relevant column.

In earlier versions, one option is a correlated subquery:

```
select value
from mytable t
where value > 1.10 * coalesce(
    (
        select t1.value 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.value < t.value
        order by t1.value desc
        limit 1
    ),
    0
)
```

To use another ordering column here, you need to change the `where` clause and the `order by` clause of the subquery.

---

On the other hand, if you want to select the next row according to the ratio against the previously selected row, then that's a different question. You need some kind of iterative process: in SQL, one approach is a recursive query:

```
with 
    data as (
        select value, row_number() over(order by value) rn
        from mytable t
    ) d,
    cte as (
        select 1 is_valid, value, rn from data where rn = 1
        union all 
        select 
            (d.value > 1.1 * c.value),
            case when d.value > 1.1 * c.value then d.value else c.value end,
            d.rn
        from cte c
        inner join data d on d.rn = c.rn + 1
    )
    select value from cte where is_valid order by value
```

The query enumerates the values, then walks the dataset sequentially while keeping track of the last selected value, and setting flags on records that should appear in the final resultset.

Comment: Now this is almost what I need, but it will not work, if we have sequence like: 100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111. It should return 100 and 111 (as the difference is over 10%), but if I understand the query correctly - it will compare each value to previous, never detecting where the change happens.

Comment: @MarcinBobowski: ok, so that's a different question... It is also more interesting. I updated my answer with a solution for what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what version of MySQL you are using, so I'll assume it's a mordern one (8.x). You can use `LAG()`. For example:

```
select
  concat('', value,
    case when prev_value is null then '' 
       else concat('', 100 * (value - prev_value) / prev_value, '%')
    end
  ) as result
from (
  select
    value,
    lag(value) over (order by value) as prev_value
  from t
) x
where prev_value is null or value > prev_value * 1.1
order by value
```